# How do I convert a JTextFeild to an Integer array?

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

Code:

```
char[] charData;
int[] data;    
JTextField message = new JTextField(60);
charData = message.getText().toUpperCase().toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < charData.length; i++){
    data[i] = (int) charData[i];             //line 62
}
for(int i : data){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I am given this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:62)
```

Line 62 is `data[i] = (int) charData[i];`

Can anyone figure it out?  I guess we will find out!

Comment: Are you expecting integers in "message"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to initialize your `data` variable, so you should move and modify its declaration to:

```
charData = message.getText().toUpperCase().toCharArray();
int[] data = new int[charData.length];
```

Now `data` will be initialized to an empty array of equal size to your array of characters.

However, of note is since you are leaving `data` uninitialized, your program should not be able to compile. Are you sure you are compiling successfully, and that this is the most up-to-date version of the code?

Comment: Your debugging is prefect but for **Compile time ** `error: variable data might not have been initialized` , not for `Null Pointer Exception`

Comment: @NeerajJain Given the supplied code, nothing else could produce the exception on that line. `charData` is is guaranteed to not be `null` since it's referenced the line before without apparent issue.

Comment: That is why mentioned your debugging is prefect , so mention the correct error which he might face , because due to this error the program will not even compile